# Why does Google docs say that the factory method pattern can reduce object creation and reduce frequent garbage collection

Tags: android

Once you identify the problem areas in your code, try to reduce the number of allocations within performance critical areas. Consider moving things out of inner loops or perhaps moving them into a Factory based allocation structure.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use object caching in factory class so when someone wants instance of the class they get object from cache a not a new object. That is how you can reduce object allocations with factory design pattern.